# Is there a R function that can duplicate entries based on length of element

Tags: r

I am trying to duplicate rows in dataframe based on length of element in column Name, for eg if length of element df$Name[1] is 3, I will duplicate the rows 3 times but each new row will have a new element in column Name derived from 2nd and 3rd element of df$Name[1]. Is there an easier way to do it in R ?

```
Dataframe looks like this
df=
Name                  c1    c2  c3
c("g7","g8","g9")   2016    82  5
g54                 2016    81  1
g5                  2016    81  4
g3                  2016    82  4
c("g1","g2")        2015    79  1
g45                 2016    82  1

Expected Result         
df2=    
Name    c1  c2  c3
g7  2016    82  5
g8  2016    82  5
g9  2016    82  5
g54 2016    81  1
g5  2016    81  4
g3  2016    82  4
g1  2015    79  1
g2  2015    79  1
g45 2016    82  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::unnest()`:

```
tidyr::unnest(df, Name)
#    c1 c2 c3 Name
#1 2016 82  5   g7
#2 2016 82  5   g8
#3 2016 82  5   g9
#4 2016 81  1  g54
#5 2016 81  4   g5
#6 2016 82  4   g3
#7 2015 79  1   g1
#8 2015 79  1   g2
#9 2016 82  1  g45
```

#### Data:

```
df <- 
structure(list(Name = list(c("g7", "g8", "g9"), "g54", "g5", 
    "g3", c("g1", "g2"), "g45"), c1 = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2015L, 2016L), c2 = c(82L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 79L, 82L), c3 = c(5L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```